# Get and Set not working with List<>

Tags: asp.net, list, properties

Im trying to make a get and set to make my List<> persistent. I think my intention is clear with the code. I want the List to remain throughout postbacks so i dont loose data in it.

What am i doing wrong? Thanks to my AlertPopUp i can see that the Get is triggered, but never the Set. So the List comes back as containint zero items when it should have several items.

```
 private List<string> accountIDsSelectedForDeletion = new List<string>();
public List<string> AccountIDsSelectedForDeletion
{
    get {
        if (ViewState["AccountIDsSelectedForDeletion"]!= null)
        {
            accountIDsSelectedForDeletion = ViewState["AccountIDsSelectedForDeletion"] as List<string>;
            AlertPopUp.QuickDebugMessage("getting list from viewstate. Count: "+ accountIDsSelectedForDeletion.Count);            
        }
        AlertPopUp.QuickDebugMessage("returning list");   
        return accountIDsSelectedForDeletion;

    }
    set {
        AlertPopUp.QuickDebugMessage("setting list to viewstate. Count: " + accountIDsSelectedForDeletion.Count); 
        accountIDsSelectedForDeletion = value;

        ViewState["AccountIDsSelectedForDeletion"] = accountIDsSelectedForDeletion;
    }
```

Comment: Could it be because i change the List by its Add() method?

Comment: When and how you add items to this list?

Comment: You perform double lookup in getter. Use `var list = ViewState[""] as List<string>; if (list != null)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could it be because i change the List by its Add() method?

In a nutshell, yes. `.Add()` is mutating the list, while the Set property acts on the list as a set piece.

To accomplish what your trying to do here, I would create an inherited type from List, so that I could inject code into the `Add` `Remove` (ext, there are more) methods. Like:

```
//not syntatically correct sorry
public class MyList : List<string>
{
    public override Add(string NewItem)
    {
        //do a extra peristance step here
        //
        me.Add(NewItem);
    }
}
```

Or have a class that wraps a private List<> and manages the Add/Remove methods, maybe like:

```
public class MyList
{
    private List<string> listItems { get; set; }
    //don't expose the list in a mutable state, IEnumerable instead
    public IEnumerable<string> Items { get { return this.listItems; } }

    public void Add(string NewItem)
    {
        this.ListItems.Add(NewItem);
    }
}
```

Then just replace List with this type on your page level class.

By the way, persisting to the `ViewState` bloats the amount of information you have to send up and down the wire per page load. Have you considered `Session`, or the `Cache` object?